# submit the current date alongside the rest of the form

Tags: php, mysql, date, post

I'm trying to get the current date to be submitted to the database without the user entering a date.

I currently have the following php code

```
<?php $currentDate = time(); ?>
```

And then within the form ive assigned the php code as a value to a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="$_POST['currentDate']">
```

this doesnt seem to work though? where am i going wrong?

Comment: `NOW()` is the current date and time for mysql `CURDATE()` if you dont want the time

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function CURDATE() in /home//mInsert.php on line 8

Comment: if goes in the mysql insert query, not the php

Comment: That date would be when the form was created, not when it was posted, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to send the date through the form. In the php code that processes your script, just use the `now()` function in the query

Like:

```
INSERT into `users` (`name`,`date`) VALUES('$name',now())
```

In your database, your `date` column must be of `date` type.

OR

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date('Y-m-d');

INSERT into `users` (`name`,`date`) VALUES('$name','$date')
```

Comment: `Now()` will use MySQL Server time. If you have or wants to use Apache/PHP on one server and MySQL on another server, and if there timezones are set different you will get different values.

Comment: use `date_default_timezone_set($timezone_identifier)` to set the timezone
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @Neil Martin hello, how can i send current data & time via HTML form

Comment: why do you want to send it through the form? That is something obtained from the server and not a user input and so it needs to be directly obtained from the server. If you still want to send it, you just create a `hidden` `input` field and `echo` or print the date/time in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If these both statements are on the same page just change:

`<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="<?php echo $currentDate; ?>">`

This will print the value of `$currentDate` in your hidden field .

Comment: this submits the record, but the date shows up as 0000-00-00

Comment: what type of database structure you are using to store the date? DATE or something else?

Comment: he needs the date. why do you need to send from the form?

Comment: @Niel Martin - Hey, everyone has their choices and preferences how to white code or implement logic :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set current date exactly to `hidden` field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="<?php echo time();">
```

And when handling the submitted data you can do:

```
$currentDate = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp((int) $_POST['mDateJoined']);
```

Comment: submits but the date on database shows up as 0000-00-00

Comment: probably you need to format this date: `$currentDate->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
<?php $currentDate = time(); ?>
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="$_POST['currentDate']">
```

are on same page. Try this instead of above code lines:

```
<?php $currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="mDateJoined" value="<?php echo $currentDate; ?>">
```

I will prefer do not pass the date as hidden field in the form and use `<?php $currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); ?>`  at the place where you are inserting the date into the database.